# Nodejs, php and express

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express

I've been tasked to create a todo list and a form that uploads png files in nodejs. These are the current packages I have:

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "0.8.5",
    "ejs-locals": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "3.4.7",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.1",
    "php-node": "0.0.2"
  }
}
```

This is my php form:

```
<form action="/Upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Select image to upload: <br>
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> <br> <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And I load it with this:

```
app.post('/Upload.php' ,function ( req, res ){
res.render("Upload.php");
});
```

This is the whole app.js:

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
require( './db' );

var express = require( 'express' );
var routes  = require( './routes' );
var http    = require( 'http' );
var php     = require( 'php-node' ); 
var path    = require( 'path' );
var app     = express();
var engine  = require( 'ejs-locals' );


// all environments
app.set( 'port', process.env.PORT || 3001 );
app.engine( 'ejs', engine );
app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, 'views' ));
app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.use( express.favicon());
app.use( express.logger( 'dev' ));
app.use( express.bodyParser());
app.use( express.json());
app.use( express.urlencoded());
app.use( express.methodOverride());
app.use( app.router );
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'public' )));

// development only
if ( 'development' == app.get( 'env' )) {
  app.use( express.errorHandler());
}

app.get( '/', routes.index );
app.get( '/edit/:id', routes.edit );
app.get( '/destroy/:id', routes.destroy );
app.post( '/create', routes.create );
app.post( '/update/:id', routes.update );

app.post('/Upload.php' ,function ( req, res ){
    res.render("Upload.php");
});

http.createServer( app ).listen( app.get( 'port' ), function(){
  console.log( 'Express server listening on port ' + app.get( 'port' ));
} );
```

Error log:

```
Express
500 Error: Cannot find module 'php'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at new View (C:\todo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:43:49)
at Function.app.render (C:\todo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:486:12)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\todo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:798:7)
at C:\todo\app.js:42:6
at callbacks (C:\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\todo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
```

Is there a way to load the .php page without changing engine?

Comment: Why do you need php here at all?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying with just nodejs and multer now. Would've been easier for me if I could have just used the .php script though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use PHP Node as your view engine along with ejs then please change set view engine as follows. I have just tested the code and it works for me

```
app.engine( 'ejs', engine );
app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
```

Comment: If I change the engine to php-node everything else will stop working. I need to keep ejs engine while being able to load the .php page.

Comment: When doing like this and accessing the page, the `php page` just downloads! instead of rendering. Any idea?